# Ruby, error with brackets for code block

Tags: ruby, iterator, codeblocks

so I am trying to understand code blocks and iterators with this simple exercise, and ran into an issue using brackets that I don't understand.

I have a 'my_times' method

```
class Integer
    def my_times
        c = 0
        until c == self
            yield(c)        # passes 'c' to code block
            c += 1
        end
        self        # return self 
    end
end
5.my_times {|i| puts "i'm on MY iteration #{i}"}
```

which works fine, then I have a 'my_each2' that operates as it should

```
class Array
    def my_each2
        size.my_times do |i|     # <-- do signifies a code block correct? 'end' is unnecessary?
            yield self[i]
        end
        self
    end
end
array.my_each2 {|e| puts "MY2 block just got handed #{e}"}
```

from my understanding the 'do |i|' in "size.my_times do |i|" is a code block (with no 'end'?) correct?
if so, then why do I get an error trying to put it in {brackets} instead of using 'do'?

```
class Array
    def my_each3
        size.my_times {|i| puts "i'm on MY iteration #{i}"} # <-- error here
            yield(self[i])
        end
        self
    end
end
array.my_each3 {|e| puts "MY3 block just got handed #{e}"}
```

but using a 'do' works

```
size.my_times do |i| puts "i'm on MY iteration #{i}"
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

'do |i|' IS a code block, the 'end' is a few lines down from it.

the complete block is

```
size.my_times do |i|     
    yield self[i]
end
```

so the correct bracketed version is

```
size.my_times { |i|  yield(self[i]) }
```

ok move on, nothing to see here :p

Answer (score -1):

> the 'do |i|' in "size.my_times do |i|" is a code block (with no 'end'?) correct?

No, it is not. `do ... end` is a code block.

> if so, then why do I get an error trying to put it in {brackets} instead of using 'do'?

Since the condition is not satisfied, the question is trivially satisfied.

Comment: what is 'do' in this context then? a postposition modifier? could you point me to the doc on this? thanks!